# R setting directory dynamically

Tags: r, if-statement

Basic R question. I can't seem to set a path dynamically in the following code (fake variables). This is part of a larger code snippet, but I've tracked it down to this.  I'm looking to check for a folder and if it exists, I'd like to create a subfolder within that directory with just the time and then save the RDS in that directory.  The code snippet below doesn't quite work.

Currently this code creates the sub-directory if the top level directory exists, but then saves the RDS in the top level directory instead of that sub-directory. Essentially whenever I run it, my_dir always comes out as whatever my_dir <- file.path(out, subbie) is set at.

```
out <- './output'
subbie <- 'Hello, World'

my_dir <- file.path(out, subbie)

my_time <- format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%b-%d")

if (file.exists(my_dir)){
  my_dir <- dir.create(my_dir, my_time)
} else {
  my_dir <- dir.create(my_dir)
}

saveRDS(my_df, file=file.path(my_dir, paste0('_', my_time, '.RDS')))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
my_dir <- dir.create(my_dir)
```

Here you are giving value `TRUE` or `FALSE` to variable `my_dir`.
Maybe if `file.exists(my_dir)` is `FALSE`, you want:
    dir.create(paste(my_dir, my_time, sep="/"), recursive=TRUE).
This will create not only the last element of the path.